# Unable to run Azure DevOps shell script tasks on Docker-Linux agent

Tags: docker, shell, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have a shell script (file.sh) with echo message. Created self hosted agent in a Linux container with the help of Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops).

Created a pipeline job with "Bash" task to run the shell script (file.sh).

End up with no outcome, though build successful. no error, no outcome on console. PFB error screen. please suggest.

[image]

[image]

Note: I am able to run same shell script from inside (docker exec -ti  bash) the container.

Comment: Can you share pipeline definition?

Comment: Pipelien definition added. only one job with one task to run shell script inside docker-Ubuntu_Linux agent.

Comment: The script is just Hello world.                                                                                
  | #!/bin/sh
# This is a comment!
echo Hello  world  |

Comment: Fixed this by making shell script executable (chmod +x file.sh) before commit and push it to git repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by making shell script executable (chmod +x file.sh) before commit and push it to git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable the System.Debug variable to true. It should show from the right top